# User password validation with his recent password history in Drupal6

Tags: validation, drupal, drupal-6, passwords, change-password

When user change his password, or admin changes any user password then it should not be same as his last 3 passwords.
How this validation can be done? I have installed `password_policy` module. But its not validating this constraint properly.
Can anybody tell me how to achieve this? I have installed `phpass` module too, is it effecting for this module?
Please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: For a more specialized Drupal response, you may want to post your Drupal questions on StackExchange's [Drupal Answers](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/?as=1).

Answer (score 2):

According to the [Password policy](http://drupal.org/project/password_policy) module page, it says that it supports:

> History constraint (checks hashed password against a collection of users previous hashed passwords looking for recent duplicates)

So my first inclination would be that `phpass` is potentially influencing this. Is it possible to **disable** the `phpass` module to test this and confirm?

In fact, according to the [Secure Password Hashes](http://drupal.org/project/phpass) module page, it is using a different algorithm to store the user's password. Since `Password policy` is storing the history of the passwords as `md5` hashes (in Drupal 6), this could cause issues if `phpass` did not take this into account.

Take a look at this related [`phpass` module issue](http://drupal.org/node/598424). You could also check the `password_policy_history` table and see if the history of password hashes for a given user matches up with the current password hash for that same user created by `phpass`.

Comment: Hi tx for your solution. There was conflit between `Password Policy` and `phpass` modules. I have disabled `phpass` module and now thr my current problem has been solved.

But now iam facing new problem. After uninstalling `phpass` module iam not able to login. Not even to admin backend too. Can you help me to solve this issue.?